# Does ADF Application Module support H2 or any other in memory database

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Does ADF Application Module support H2 or any other in memory database? 
i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection while creating the Application Module for testing

Comment: Provide some more information. Are you connecting to oracle DB? Also, please share some more error log.

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose to use the generic JDBC and JDBC types when you created your ADF BC layer?
Did you add the JDBC driver to JDeveloper's project libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps to use H2 database properly in your ADF application.

1. Create H2 db connection in your application
2. Run your integrated weblogic server
3. Create data source with same name as you have created connection in first step
4. Create AM, EO, VO and page of your add application

This way you will not get class cast exception.

Regards,
Bhavesh